# Unique constraint with null value interpreted as any value

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-constraint

Consider table

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    col1 integer NOT NULL,
    col2 integer NOT NULL,
    col3 integer
)
```

I need to check uniqueness on `(col1, col2, col3)`, with NULL in `col3` meaning any value. That is, if there is a row `(1, 2, NULL)` in the table, it will be impossible to insert a row with `col1 = 1`, `col2 = 2` and any value in `col3` (including NULL). Conversely, if there is at least one row with `col1 = 1` and `col2 = 2` and some not NULL value in `col3` in the table, you cannot insert a row `(1, 2, NULL)`, but the row with `col1 = 1`, `col2 = 2` and any value in `col3` (except NULL) will valid.

For example, these values are valid (first id column is omitted):

```
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 2, 5)
```

or

```
(1, 2, NULL)
(1, 3, NULL)
```

But these values are invalid:

```
(1, 2, NULL)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 4)
```

or

```
(1, 2, NULL)
(1, 2, NULL)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 4)
```

Can I do this by PostgreSQL? I'm using version 9.6.5.

Comment: This is not really possible, because you are assuming an ordering to the inserts.  You can insert multiple rows at the same time, so it is unclear which version of the rules to use if there are `NULL` conflicts.

Comment: So, basically you want to treat NULL as a value. You could either use a sentinel value (such as `-1`) and make col3 not NULLable, or you could use a `(col1,col2,COALESCE(col3, -1))` expression to construct the index.

Comment: @joop no actually. I want to treat NULL as not particular value but as any possible value. So your approach is not valid unfortunately - see the first example for invalid values in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting check if there is a row with :

```
col1=your_col1_value 
col2=your_col2_value
col3=null
```

if so don't insert your row.

Use an insert select : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html

And a not exist : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html

Comment: You mean triggers I guess, but I find some solution based on indexes (sorry if I not stated it in the question).